# Webform hours/time field

Tags: 7, entities, webforms

How do you add a field where user can set hours when it's best to call for contacting. The Date field gives only days, months and years.

In this thread [Webform: Time Field - Changing Variable Increments](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112485/webform-time-field-changing-variable-increments) he states he has some time field for his Webform. But I can't track it down which module is that?

Answer (score 1):

[Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module have time field by default.